# painting inequalities regions with pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I'm trying to paint a region of a plane but I can't manage to find a way.

It should look like this:

[image]

Also if there is a way to change the painting of the region for it to be like the ones a painted it would be perfectt, here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{tikz}  
\usepackage{mathtools}  
\usepackage[siunitx, american]{circuitikz} 
\usepackage{enumitem}   
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}    
\usepackage{titling} 
\usepackage{changepage}  
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{geometry}   
\usepackage{xfrac}  
\usepackage{pgfplots}  
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}  
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}  

\begin{document} 

\begin{figure}[H] \centering
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis} [xmin = -0.7, xmax = 1.7, ymin = -1.5, ymax = 1.5, xlabel =$\phi_1$, ylabel =$\phi_2$, axis lines = middle,width = 8cm, height=7cm , title = Constelación de Señales, ytick distance = 3, xtick distance = 5]

    \node[label={180:{(0,$\sqrt{T}$)}},circle,fill,inner sep=2pt] at (axis cs:0,1) {}; 
    \node[label={},circle,fill,inner sep=2pt] at (axis cs:1,0) {}; 
    \node [above = 1mm] at (axis cs:1,0) {($\sqrt{T}$,0)}; 
    \node[label={180:{(0,$-\sqrt{T}$)}},circle,fill,inner sep=2pt] at (axis cs:0,-1) {}; 

    \addplot +[const plot, no marks, black] 
    coordinates{(0,0) (-0.7,0)};  
    \addplot[name path=b, domain=0:1.7] {x} \closedcycle node at (current path bounding box.center) {};  
    \addplot[name path=a, domain=0:1.7] {-x} \closedcycle node at (current path bounding box.center) {};
    \addplot[gray!30] fill between[of=b and a]; 
    \path[name path=axisl] (axis cs:-1,0) -- (axis cs:0,0); 




\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}  


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add some patterns.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}  
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}  
\usetikzlibrary{patterns.meta}
\begin{document} 

\begin{figure} \centering
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis} [xmin = -0.7, xmax = 1.7, ymin = -1.5, ymax = 1.5, xlabel
=$\phi_1$, ylabel =$\phi_2$, axis lines = middle,width = 8cm, height=7cm , title
= Constelaci\'on de Se\~nales, ytick distance = 3, xtick distance = 5]
    \path[pattern={Lines[angle=45,distance={3pt/sqrt(2)}]},pattern color=blue]
     (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},0) -- (0,0) --
     (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax}) -| cycle;
    \path[pattern={Lines[angle=-45,distance={3pt/sqrt(2)}]},pattern color=blue]
    (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},0) -- (0,0) --
    (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax}) -| cycle;

    \node[label={180:{(0,$\sqrt{T}$)}},circle,fill,inner sep=2pt] at (axis cs:0,1) {}; 
    \node[label={},circle,fill,inner sep=2pt] at (axis cs:1,0) {}; 
    \node [above = 1mm] at (axis cs:1,0) {($\sqrt{T}$,0)}; 
    \node[label={180:{(0,$-\sqrt{T}$)}},circle,fill,inner sep=2pt] at (axis cs:0,-1) {}; 

    \addplot +[const plot, no marks, black] 
    coordinates{(0,0) (-0.7,0)};  
    \addplot[name path=b, domain=0:1.7] {x} \closedcycle node at (current path bounding box.center) {};  
    \addplot[name path=a, domain=0:1.7] {-x} \closedcycle node at (current path bounding box.center) {};
    \addplot[gray!30] fill between[of=b and a]; 
    \path[name path=axisl] (axis cs:-1,0) -- (axis cs:0,0); 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}  
\end{document}
```

[image]

From the syntax it should be obvious how one can change the color, density and slopes of these lines.

On a different note, I'd kindly ask you not to add unrelated packages to the preamble of your MWE, nor to load packages twice.